# How to fix box-shadow animation on iOS

Tags: css, css-animations

I have project I’m working on and cannot seem to get it to animate/display properly on iOS.

I have tried adding `-webkit-` to my `@keyframes` and `box-shadow` but that didn’t solve it. I also enabled CodePen’s Autoprefixer which didn’t help.

The animation seems to work just fine on my Windows system but not on my iPhone or MacBook. I think the problem is related to `animation-timing-function: steps...` but am not 100% sure.

Any help would be appreciated.

https://codepen.io/jfirestorm44/pen/GRZRPew